# Can we affect nuclear warheads with neutrinos?

Tags: nuclear-physics, estimation, neutrinos, nuclear-engineering

I heard, that we can either disarm or detonate nuclear warhead if we could target neutrino beam onto it. Is it true? Which reaction it would be? Conversion of neutrons to protons? Or conversion of protons to neutrons?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93007/ Does that answer your question?

Comment: Partially. What reaction do neutrinos cause inside a bomb?

Comment: The basic reactions are: neutron + neutrino -> proton + electron and proton + antineutrino -> neutron + positron.

Answer (score 6):

The paper [Sugawara, H., Hagura, H., & Sanami, T. (2003). Destruction of Nuclear Bombs Using Ultra-High Energy Neutrino Beam. arXiv preprint hep-ph/0305062](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0305062v1) analyses this, in my opinion overly optimistically.

The basic idea is to generate muons that are allowed to decay into tight neutrino beams (plus, of course other particles that will heat up some nearby rock or material). They find that for a 1000 TeV beam this can still be tightly aimed through the Earth, depositing about 1 Sv/s at the target (and in the rock beneath). The higher the energy, the more the neutrinos interact with matter, so the better at messing up bombs the beam becomes. But equally, more gets absorbed by the Earth. However, earlier interactions also produce a strongly interacting hadron shower, which is also likely to heat and trigger fission.

They then assume the way the beam disables the bomb is that it heats up the core to 300 C and this destroys the explosives surrounding it, plus the hadrons producing a subcritical nuclear fizzle.

The problem is not just that you need an accelerator dwarfing the LHC and enormous energy, but that their time estimates indicates about 100 seconds per warhead - and there are thousands in the world. The beam needs to be directed with meter precision, yet you normally do not know in what part of a complex the warheads are stored. Plus, the hadron shower is in itself a pretty nasty weapon - if you can do this, you have a way of killing anybody in the world who you know the exact position of. So the world doesn't become safer at all... At least it will be pretty obvious who did the hadronic assassination.

It is still an interesting radiation physics exercise.

Answer (score 2):

> [The researchers suggest](https://physicsworld.com/a/could-neutrinos-destroy-nuclear-weapons/) sending a neutrino beam with an energy of 1000 TeV through the Earth to wherever the nuclear weapon was located (see figure). The beam would produce neutrons in a ‘hadron shower’ and would cause fission reactions in the plutonium or uranium in the bomb. These reactions would either melt or vaporize the bomb.

It is complete science fiction in my opinion . LHC has reached 14 TeV with great expense and technological advancements.

> Which reaction it would be? Conversion of neutrons to protons?

As you see, it is simple neutrino + [the nucleus of everything in front of the bomb]  scattering, generating a lot of neutrons some of which will start the fission  reaction and get the bomb going.

> Finally there is the risk, the authors point out, that the interaction of the neutrino beam with the bomb “could lead to a full explosion” instead of eliminating it.

Found the [arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0305062v1).

Comment: This method looks irrelevant to both neutrinos and nuclear fission: neutrinos are converted to neutrons and for habitants of target site it will look like neutron radiation emiting from under the ground. Okay, thanks. But are there any other methods? Being a source of neutrinos itself, could nuclear bomb or reactor core has some selectivity in absorbing neutrinos? (kindof reversibility princible)

Comment: @Dims neutrinos go through the earth without problems because they are weakly interacting. There is a very  small probability a neutrino to interact with a nucleus in your body, and the damage will be loca;l to the cell that has the nucleus, and our cells are replaceable. but if 1000TeV hits in a nucleus in a bomb, the number of secondary neutrons coming out of such a hadronic reaction can set fission going. That is what the paper is about, estimating energies and densities etc with computer programs.